# Browser Connection is lost to IIS 7.5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, iis-7.5

We are experiencing a strange problem.  We have a number of dev machines and on some of them we have no problems, and on others it is as if the server is completely unaware of the browser and visa versa.

The solution is ASP.NET MVC written in C# running on IIS 7.5 (Windows 7 64 bit)

The symptoms:

- Session variables are null on every request
- using(Html.BeginForm()) doesn't work properly.  You can submit a form multiple times, starting many threads on the server and the response throws the "the remote host closed the connection" exception

3 machines are working fine - 2 are not.  We are pulling our hair out with this one.  It obviously has something to do with the IIS setup or config but we cannot find the problem.  We have even done a screen by screen compare on the IIS setup between two machines - one that works and one that doesn't

Any help would be greatly appreciated

--Update - this is happening in a mixed environment (ASP.NET and ASP.NET MVC).  The global.asax on the ASP.NET site runs, but the MVC global.asax doesn't run.  How does one force the global.asax to run?

-- Another update - this only happens in IE 9 - not Chrome.  Beginning to make good headway on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if we've solved all the issues, but this piece of code certainly works on IE9 for blocking a 2nd request while the first request is still processing:

```
@using TestMixedApp.MVC.Models
@model TestModel

@{
Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<title>Index</title>
<script src="/TestMixedApp.MVC/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function disableSubmitButton() {
        $("#submitbutton").attr("disabled", true);
        $("#message").html("&nbsp;processing...");
    };
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { autocomplete = "off", onsubmit = "disableSubmitButton()" }))
    {
       <tr>
        <td>@Html.LabelFor(m=>m.Firstname)</td>
        <td>@Html.EditorFor(m=>m.Firstname)</td>
       </tr> 
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.LabelFor(m=>m.Surname)</td>
            <td>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Surname)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Previous Firstname</td>
            <td>@Model.Firstname</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Previous Surname</td>
            <td>@Model.Surname</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Go" id="submitbutton"/><span id="message"></span></td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
</body>
</html>
```